# Best way to sequence Flex/Actionscript method/function method calls

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, asynchronous, sequence, synchronous

OK, from what I know actionscript in Flex runs asynchronously. I need the ability to run a method in a loop synchronously. Consider this code:

```
public class CustomerContainer extends VBox
{

    public function CustomerContainer ()
    {
        super();
        addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, 
                         this_creationCompleteHandler);

    }

    public function build():void
    {
                   //process something here

    }
}
```

Now we have a for loop in our MXML file

```
<mx:Script>
<![CDATA[

    private var newContainer:CustomerContainer;

    public function foo():void
    {
      for (var i:int = 0; i < EndingNumber; i++)
      {

        newContainer  = new CustomerContainer();
        newContainer.build();//I need this to finish before it goes on to the 
        // next one. here is where the problem is flex runs through this loop 
        // creating each new object but I do not know if the first 1 object is 
        // complete before it begin processing the second one in the For Loop. 
      }
    }
   ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

This is not my exact situation as it is a bit more complicated to explain here. There is an abstract class and several custom view objects derived from it. Some of the views are dependent on others being completed first but I cannot seem to order them in the correct order. TIMERS are not an option. Probably not explaining this correctly.

Comment: Given the code you've shown, it should run synchronously exactly as you wish.  Are you sure of the results you're seeing?  I suspect something else must be going on, such as the use of an Asynchronous remote call inside the build method.  Can you provide a full runnable sample?  Without knowing your 'build' code it is hard to guess what you mean by "completed"; nor what "order" you are referring to.

Comment: Agree with Flextras, not seeing a problem here.  Are you actually experiencing an issue?  The way your question is worded makes it sound like you are anticipating a problem that may not exist.

Comment: Actionscript is not running asynchronously. If that would be the case then coding it would be very funny. Maybe your code is calling asynchronous methods(a service call)?

Comment: @mikej, can I ask what's the purpose of this?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Task](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/cairngorm/wiki/CairngormLibraries/#Task) library from Cairngorm.

It provides a way to order units of work, and have them run sequentially, in parallel, or both.

Otherwise, dealing with event listeners, and error conditions quickly gets out of hand.

Comment: Or even better, the [task framework from Spicelib](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.4/manual/) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I like solving this the Lisp-y way:

```
// tell this function to start creating. 
private function initContainers( count:int ):void
{
     if( count <= 0 ) return;
     var newContainer:CustomerContainer = new CustomerContainer();
     newContainer.build();
     /* ... stuff happens ... */ 
     newContainer.addEventListener( FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE,
                                    function( fe:FlexEvent ):void
                                    {
                                        // tell the function to create one fewer
                                        initContainers( count - 1 );
                                    } );
}
```

Your sequence:

1. initContainers( x ) ->

   1. create container.
   2. wait for event ->
2. initContainers( x - 1 );

   1. create container.
   2. wait for event -> `<!-- lots o' more -->`